# Accorder, sujet ou COD ?

Tags: accord, participe-passé, sujet

Dans la phrase suivante:

> Félicitations pour votre implication qui vous aura conduit à la réussite.

On ne devrait pas plutôt écrire *conduit**e*** ? 
Le sujet est « implication », qui est féminin, je mettrais donc plutôt *conduite*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pas d'accord, parce que le verbe est conjugué avec *avoir*. On fait l'accord avec le sujet uniquement quand l'[auxiliare](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs/) est *être*.

Par contre, si *vous* est féminin, il y aura accord - les verbes avec *avoir* s'accordent avec leur [objet direct précédent](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/agreement-with-direct-objects/).

Comment: Je n'ai absolument pas pensé à "avoir" et "être", bien vu.

Comment: Dans l'exemple de ton second lien, ils mettent *Je vais acheter la voiture que tu as recommandée.*. Ils accordent bien avec le verbe avoir. En quoi ma phrase est différente ?

Comment: *Recommandée* est au féminin pour s'accorder avec l'objet direct *la voiture*. Tu avais voulu s'accorder avec le sujet, qui ne se fait pas.

Comment: La différence, c'est le [pronom relatif](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/relative-pronouns/).   (1) *qui* dans ta phrase indique que *l'implication* est le sujet = il ne s'accorde pas.  (2) *que* dans l'autre phrase indique que *la voiture* est l'object direct = il s'accorde.

Comment: @Vadorequest dans l'exemple "Je vais acheter la voiture que tu as recommandée", le problème est que le COD est AVANT le verbe (tu as recommandé quoi ? la voiture). Dans l'exemple de la question il n'y a pas de COD, uniquement un COI, après le verbe (vous aura conduit à quoi ? à la réussite)